# Duplicated jquery definition using grails assets

Tags: grails, asset-pipeline, assets

If I have two independent assets that depends on jquery and use both in the same page the jquery js is included twice.

```
file1.js
//= require jquery
//= require plugin1.js

file2.js
//= require jquery
//= require plugin2.js
```

in HTML file:

```
<asset:javascript src="file1.js" />
<asset:javascript src="file2.js" />
```

How do I achieve that only one jquery is included?

Comment: Does it really matter? The second call will be served from the browser cache.

Comment: It matters when you use twitter bootstrap JS. They bind the init functions to $ variable. But when you access these functions from your script, you access different jquery variable and then you don't have these functions.

Comment: Don't include jquery in both of them?

Comment: But what if I use file2.js alone in other web page where jquery is necessary? Before using the asset plugin, this was never a problem in Grails 2 and it could resolve dependencies.

Comment: Honestly the whole point of a manifest file is too define all your dependencies in a single file. Why are you using two manifests?

Comment: @ToddSharp I don't understand what do you mean? How should I structure the js require definitions then? What if I want to use the same file in 2 different places? Should I define for every usage place its own manifest? Let's say file2.js has 10 different dependencies and I use this file in 2 pages. In page 1, I need 10 deps, in page 2, there are already 2 deps available. Should I define a new manifest with only 8 remaning deps?

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that deduplication has been added in grails-asset-pipeline in version 3.0.0
https://github.com/bertramdev/asset-pipeline/commit/f8bd3d701a5fe14a30f5d89c6e8796f590d4643b#diff-0a3b83b6f81080c1f7f0486f9d5ae1a6

This feature is not yet documented, but according to the source code, we use follwing syntax which ensures, that duplicates are removed within same request:

```
    <asset:javascript src="myScript.js" uniq="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simply how asset pipeline works. If you have a page that needs both of those files, create a new manifest

```
file3.js

//= require file1.js
//= require file2.js
```

Then just include file3 on the page

`<asset:javascript src="file3.js" />`

Comment: I'm quite confused because in the previous versions of Grails (2.xx), where Resources plugin was used, this was never a problem. Will the dependent js files be resolved only once then? e.g. if both file1.js and file2.js requires jquery like in the example above?

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure where your confusion comes from as this is a completely different plugin than Resources, therefore it works differently.

Comment: I know it's a different plugin, but it's used in Grails. And since it's newer version, one would expect it's used in a similar way as in the old Grails. In the docs, there are nothing about what should you put in a HTML and how the duplication is (not) resolved, so I thought you use it old way. Thanks for clarification!

Comment: One more question: I have `common.js` which is used in every page. This `common.js` depends on `jquery.js`. Now on one specific page I have `file1.js` that has also a dependency on `jquery.js`. Is it possible to include `common.js` in `g:layoutHeader` so I can have it in all my pages, but also to avoid the jquery duplication on the one specific page where I also use  `file1.js`?

Comment: No 12 more to go

Comment: What do you mean?